# Unable to set time difference as time interval for local notifications

Tags: swift, xcode

I have calculated the time difference from 2 timings:

```
func timeDiff() {
    let time1 = currentTimeOutlet
    let time2 = alarmTimeOutlet

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mma"

    let date1 = formatter.date(from: time1!.text!)
    let date2 = formatter.date(from: time2!.text!)

    var elapsedTime = date2!.timeIntervalSince(date1!)

    if (elapsedTime < 0) {
        elapsedTime = elapsedTime + 86400
        UserDefaults.standard.set(elapsedTime, forKey: "TIME")
    }
    else {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(elapsedTime, forKey: "TIME")
    }

    elapsedTimeSecOutlet.text = String(elapsedTime)
    let hours = floor(elapsedTime / 60 / 60)
    let minutes = floor((elapsedTime - (hours * 60 * 60)) / 60)
    timeDiffOutlet.text = ("\(Int(hours)) hr and \(Int(minutes)) min")
}
```

I am trying to set the time interval in local notification to be this calculated time difference (elapsedTime), once I click on a button:

```
@IBAction func defaultOnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    defaultOffOutlet.isHidden = false
    timeDiff()

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
        if granted {
            print("Yay!")
        } else {
            print("Dh.")
        }
    }
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Rise & Shine"
    content.subtitle = "Let's start the day!!!!!!"

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: elapsedTime, repeats: false)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "timeElapsed", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
}
```

The local notification works when I set the timeinterval as an integer (e.g. 20.0), however when I replace it with "elapsedTime", xcode prompts me to change it to **TimeInterval(elapsedTime)**.

I changed it to TimeInterval(elapsedTime). However, when I build the app, the build succeeds, but the app will crash once I click the button. I have checked that the button works with other code, and works once I change the timeinterval back to an integer.

Anyone has any advice? Is it possible to set my time interval as a variable?

Thank you very very much much!

Comment: TimeInterval in swift is typealias of type Double. When your set time interval as 20.0 its not integer as you mentioned in post, it's a double value. Whereas 86400 value you are adding to time interval is integer value, thats why its asking to change it to TimeInterval(elapsedTime) i.e. double. It should be 86400.0. Check with it.

Comment: @sinner thank you for yr response!

I’ve tried to change it to TimeInterval(elapsed Time) as prompted by xcode. the app build normally but when I click the button to trigger this local notification, the app crashes.

Am unsure what I could do next & am hoping someone may be able to assist! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

time difference method update. try this code for time difference. I get notification after 1 minute

```
let time1 = NSDate() //update your time
let minutes1: TimeInterval = 1 * 60
let time2 = Date() + minutes1 //update your time

var formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
let strdate1 = formatter.string(from: time1 as Date)
formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
let date1 = formatter.date(from: strdate1)

formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
let strdate2 = formatter.string(from: time2)
formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
let date2 = formatter.date(from: strdate2)

var elapsedTime = date2!.timeIntervalSince(date1!)

if (elapsedTime < 0) {
    elapsedTime = elapsedTime + 86400
    UserDefaults.standard.set(elapsedTime, forKey: "TIME")
}
else {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(elapsedTime, forKey: "TIME")
}
```

Hope this is help you.